# Distribuir lista de <li> em duas colunas

Tags: html, css

Estou tentando criar uma lista com 4 blocos, porém os mesmos não ficam alinhados lado-a-lado de forma correta, estão assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria que ficassem assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

HTML:

```
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
```

CSS

```
#test li {
    width: 230px;
    height: 140px;
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid red;
    background: #999;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Por que não estão alinhando?

Comment: A seção pai tem tamanho fixo? Os `float: left` não vão ajudar se a seção ocupar um tamanho variável com o redimensionar do browser.

Comment: Não entendi, amigo, como assim seção pai?

Comment: `<div id="pai"><ol><li></li></ol></div>` Neste caso, sua `<ol>` ou sua `<div>` tem `width` especificado? Ou quando você redimensiona o browser os seus `<li>` vão se movendo?

Comment: Sim, a div tem o tamanho de 1000px.

Comment: Neste caso o `float: left` vai fazer o elemento flutuar e preencher o espaço que estiver disponível. Você precisa aumentar o tamanho do `width` do seus `li` (algo como 500px talvez) ou mudar de `li` para `div`.

Answer (score 7):

Segue uma solução CSS3 que leva em conta vários fatores:

- Largura variável: você pode mexer no tamanho da UL, que as células acompanharão;
- Segurança ao definir os 50% para não "estourar" o espaço disponível por inconsistências do browser;
- Inclui a solução para o "quadriculado" das cores em CSS (mesmo que seja só pra ilustrar, é legal saber como se faz);

```css
html, body, ul {      /* aqui o que importa é o UL, o resto é pra estética do demo.          */
  position:relative;  /* reset do position, não relacionado ao demo, mas bom pra uso geral.  */
  margin:0;           /* Zeramos as margens e o padding do UL para as células.encostarem     */
  padding:0;
  width:100%;         /* por default, os blocos são 100%, mas vamos garantir isso.           */
  height:100%;        /* aqui foi feito pra fins de demonstração apenas.                     */
}


li {
  display:block;             /* primeiro passo, transformar o LI em bloco.                   */ 
  list-style-type: none;     /* depois, remoção dos bullets.                                 */
  margin:0;                  /* nao queremos espaços ente os blocos.                         */
  background-color:#666;     /* cor de fundo principal, o "grid" fazemos depois              */
  box-sizing: border-box;    /* medidas são de borda à borda, o padding não é acrescentado.  */
  height:25%;                /* esta linha é pela estética do demo                           */
}

li:nth-child(odd) {          /* este css será aplicato nos LI impares (1, 3, 5... ).         */
  clear:both;                /* forçamos a quebra de linha por segurança...                  */
  float:left;                /* ... e o alinhamos à esquerda.                                */
  width:50%;                 /* Aplicamos 50% na esquerda, os da direita "herdam" o resto.   */
}

li:nth-child(4n+2),          /* aqui pulamos de 4 em 4 itens começando do 2 ( 2, 6, ...).    */
li:nth-child(4n+3) {         /* aqui de 4 em 4 começando do 3 ( 3, 7, ... )                  */
  background-color:#444;     /* e mudamos a cor, dando efeito de quadriculado                */
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado, cara!

Answer (score 5):

Você poderia fazer isso afetando apenas os blocos ímpares:

```css
ul li {
  width: 230px;
  height: 140px;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: #999;
  overflow: hidden;
}

ul li:nth-child(odd) {
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
```

```
<ul>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado, cara!

Comment: Cara, e se eu quiser acrescentar mais um bloco só que maior, ficando 4 de 230x140px e outro 250x280px, o maior no início e os 4 ao lado? eu tentei, mas ficou um "pra fora"

Comment: Ex: 
http://s18.postimg.org/cmwrc02ux/Untitled_1.jpg

Comment: @user3386417 isso ainda é uma lista? Parece uma row com três colunas. Seria interessante você criar uma nova pergunta com a imagem e o código, aqui fica complicado responder.

Comment: isso @NGTHM4R3, marca essa a que atendeu melhor como resposta, cita em uma nova pergunta essa pergunta, mas que agora precisa de mais um bloco, so que maior a esquerda. E certeza que rápidinho a gente responde, serio, a galera responde muuuito rápido, eu nem consigo responder :/

Answer (score 3):

Você também pode definir a largura como sendo 50%

```css
ul{width: 400px; height: 400px; list-style:none; margin:0; padding: 0; font-family: Arial; color: #FFF; font-size: 1.5em}
li{float: left; width:50%; height: 50%; padding: 0; background-color: #292929;}
li:first-child, li:last-child{background-color: #222222 !important;}
li > span{display: block; width: 100%; text-align: center; padding: 44% 0;}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span>1</span></li>
  <li><span>2</span></li>
  <li><span>3</span></li>
  <li><span>4</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: E a Navalha de Ockham ataca novamente. :)

Answer (score 0):

Atribuindo o display: inline-block resolve em parte, você também pode adicionar width para quebrar de acordo com o tamanho. Espero que dessa vez ajude e esclareça as dúvidas. Segue link muito bom: http://pt-br.learnlayout.com/inline-block.html

```
ul {width: 30px;}
ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Porque não fornece resposta? Deveria era ser melhorada.

Comment: Responder apenas com código não explica o real procedimento para resolução do problema. Tente editar sua resposta.

Comment: @CelsomTrindade concordo com o JorgeB, o único problema da resposta e não dar uma explicação sobre a resolução, mas não há nada de errado em colocar só código (mesmo que seja uma só linha).

Comment: @Omni Mas neste caso, o que o código dele vai fazer pra resolver o problema? como vai ajudar? Apenas mudar para inline-block não responde e muito menos resolve o problema.

Answer (score 0):

Eu particularmente prefiro usando "display: inline-block", pois usando usando float faz com que o elemento pai(no caso a "ul") perca a altura, e com isso voce precisa de mais propriedade(s) para que a "ul" não perca altura.

```css
ul {
  font-size: 0;
}
ul li {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 140px;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: #999;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

Solução correta:

```
ul {
    -moz-column-count: 4;
    -moz-column-gap: 20px;
    -webkit-column-count: 4;
    -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
    column-count: 4;
    column-gap: 20px;
}
```

Referência:  https://www.w3.org/TR/css-multicol-1/

Comment: Não, não é a solução correta amigo

Comment: Você diz que não. Qual solução semântica então você daria sem JS e que o CSS já provê isso?

Comment: Ta vendo o CSS dele, está assim `#test li {...`, provavelmente quer dizer que antes da LI deve ter a UL com o ID `test`, outra coisa, seu CSS não funciona, não está como a imagem de exemplo de referencia. E achei estranho vc falar que é a "resposta correta", pq as outras não são, já tem resposta falando de UL, e o CSS aqui não resolve a pergunta... foi só uma observação ok, testa ai o seu código que vc vai ver

Comment: Dei exemplo das propriedades CSS, nao em cima do exemplo do cara. Mostrei as pripriedades que devem ser utilizadas apenas.